# Document.ChangeListener are removed in Couchbase Lite

Tags: android, couchbase, couchbase-lite, changelistener

I'm using Couchbase Lite with Android. I have a document on which I need to add a Document.ChangeListener (to update UI whenever this document change).

I add it but it seems to be removed "automagically" and I can't find out why. I have a method "attachDocumentChangeListener" that I call :

```
public void attachDocumentChangeListener(String documentId, final DocumentChangeListener<TData> listener) {
       getDefaultDatabase().getDocument(documentId).addChangeListener(listener);
}
```

I don't touch my device anymore and I make an update on the document via another device. This should trigger the ChangeEvent but does not seem to happen.

I noticed that when the document is updated, the document has no `ChangeListener` (even if I added one juste before). To check when does the `ChangeListener` is removed I added a breakpoint to the function `removeChangeListener(ChangeListener changeListener)` from `Document` class but is has never been called and the field `changeListeners` was still empty when the revision was updated.

I added another breakpoint, a field watchpoint on `changeListeners`. Here is a screenshot of the configuration of this breakpoint :

[image]

And I repeated the operation (updating the document with another device) but I didn't see anything but the logs that show a ChangeListener has been removed (without knowing how)

```
{com.couchbase.lite.Document@6.888}.changeListeners will be accessed at com.couchbase.lite.Document.addChangeListener(Document.java:169)
size : 0, ID : 8980450c-5ddb-4181-a7bf-3e162c67a68f
{com.couchbase.lite.Document@6.888}.changeListeners will be accessed at com.couchbase.lite.Document.addChangeListener(Document.java:169)
size : 1, ID : 8980450c-5ddb-4181-a7bf-3e162c67a68f
{com.couchbase.lite.Document@9.975}.changeListeners will be accessed at com.couchbase.lite.Document.addChangeListener(Document.java:169)
size : 0, ID : 8980450c-5ddb-4181-a7bf-3e162c67a68f
{com.couchbase.lite.Document@10.189}.changeListeners will be accessed at com.couchbase.lite.Document.revisionAdded(Document.java:598)
size : 0, ID : 8980450c-5ddb-4181-a7bf-3e162c67a68f
{com.couchbase.lite.Document@10.189}.changeListeners will be accessed at com.couchbase.lite.Document.revisionAdded(Document.java:598)
size : 0, ID : 8980450c-5ddb-4181-a7bf-3e162c67a68f
```

We can see that `removeChangeListener` has never been called but `changeListeners` size has been set to 0.

Anyone could help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Document.ChangeListener` is associated with the `Document` instance. I believe following stuff could be happened.

1. Obtain Document instance (Document@6.888) with doc ID `8980450c-5ddb-4181-a7bf-3e162c67a68f`.
2. Added Document.ChangeListener to the document instance.
3. Document instance is released (garbage collected).
4. Obtain Document instance (Document@9.975) with same doc ID.
5. But this instance does not have Document.ChangeListener, and unable to notify the changes.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find out why this was happening but I managed to fix this issue by listening to changes through Database.ChangeListener instead of Document.ChangeListener. When I call `attachDocumentChangeListener(Document.ChangeListener)`, I add the listener into a `Map<String,Document.ChangeListener>` (where the key document id) and when a document is updated, it goes through the `Database.ChangeListener.changed()` method and here is how I override it :

```
@Override
public void changed(Database.ChangeEvent event) {
    for (DocumentChange change : event.getChanges()) {
        List<DocumentChangeListener> documentChangeListeners = this.documentChangeListeners.get(change.getDocumentId());
        if(documentChangeListeners != null){
            for (DocumentChangeListener changeListener : documentChangeListeners)
                changeListener.changed(change);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my 2 methods `attachDocumentChangeListener()` & `detachDocumentChangeListener()`.

```
public void attachDocumentChangeListener(String documentId, final DocumentChangeListener listener){
    List<DocumentChangeListener> documentChangeListeners = this.documentChangeListeners.get(documentId);
    if(documentChangeListeners == null)
        documentChangeListeners = new ArrayList<>();

    documentChangeListeners.add(listener);
    this.documentChangeListeners.put(documentId, documentChangeListeners);
}

public void detachDocumentChangeListener(@NonNull DocumentChangeListener listener){
    String documentId = listener.getDocumentId();
    List<DocumentChangeListener> documentChangeListeners = this.documentChangeListeners.get(documentId);
    if(documentChangeListeners != null){
        documentChangeListeners.remove(listener);
        if(documentChangeListeners.isEmpty())
            this.documentChangeListeners.remove(documentId);
        else
            this.documentChangeListeners.put(documentId, documentChangeListeners);
    }
}
```

And those 3 methods are inside a Singleton.